# Вывод количества букв а и о с помощью tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть код, который дали на изменение, с библиотекой tkinter сталкиваюсь впервые, поэтому не знаю что делать, попросили сделать код с выводом текста, который ты вводишь в фрэйм, при том текст должен содержать вывод количества букв 'а' и 'о'.

Та самая часть кода:

```
import tkinter

self = tkinter.Tk()
self.geometry('600x400')

def click():
    label.config(text=entry.get()) 

frame = tkinter.Frame(self)
frame.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame)
entry.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(frame)
label.pack()
button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Печать!', command=click)
quit_button = tkinter.Button(text='Выход', command=self.destroy)
quit_button.pack()
button.pack()
self.mainloop()
```

Нужно, что бы текст, отправляемый в button был выведен в лэйбл как  количество введённых букв 'а' и 'о'

Comment: Вы хоть раз прочли то, что сами написали? "Нужно, что бы текст, отправляемый в button был как количество введённых букв 'а' и 'о'" - это как???  А на вопрос "не знаю что делать" -  ответ один: найдите книжку по tkinter и прочитайте. Или хотя-бы сайт какой. И не беритесь за работу, которая не соответствует вашей квалификации. На этом сайте помогают тем кто что-то делает сам. А не решают ваши задачи вместо вас.

Comment: Это не работа, а задание в институте, а на счёт того, читал я или нет - да, читал, и множество сайтов перерыл с похожими темами

Comment: И что, перерыли множество сайтов и прочитали множество книг и не нашли ответа, как сделать элементарную задачу? Вот действительно -  никакой информации? Это совершенно уникальная и суперсложная задача? Или не нашли готового решения, которое можно скопипастить и выдать за свое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> с библиотекой tkinter сталкиваюсь

это стандартная библиотека, знать её обязательно, плюсом будет киви, qt5, wx

```
textvar=tkinter.StringVar()
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame,textvar=textvar)
entry.pack()
def my_function():
    print(textvar.get())
    #тут код обработки и вывода результата
button = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Печать!', command=my_function)
```

Comment: Я через принт пробовал чуток по другому, он не мог прочитать тип данных, блин, спасибо огромное

Comment: Там тоже с чекбоксами и цифровыми значениями, но помниться вроде  был доступ через виджет к тексту, но не уверен. & на здоровье